# Broken Behavior with Vanilla JS setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an animation on my hamburger-style menu written with HTML, CSS, and Vanilla JavaScript.

## Intened Results

When you click the hamburger menu button the following events should happen:

### When the hamburger menu icon is clicked:

1. The `main` rotates to 180° and shrinks height-wise across `2000ms`
2. After `2000ms` has passed the menu appears and the hamburger icon changes to an `X`

### When the exit button is clicked:

1. Cover the menu by rotating the page another 180°
2. Hide the menu with: `display: none;`
3. Convert the exit button back to a hamburger icon

## What actually happens

The main problem is when the exit button doesn't because of `settimeout` at lines 12-14.
Here's a code snippet for better understanding.

```js
var exitButton = document.getElementById("exit-button");


var exitButtonOnClick = function() {
  mobileMenu.classList.add("hidden");
}
var mobileMenuButton = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-enter");
var mobileMenu = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-id");
var mainContent = document.getElementById("main-content")

var mobileMenuButtonOnClick = function() {
  mainContent.classList.toggle("moved-away")
  setTimeout(function() {
    mobileMenu.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }, 2000);




  if (mobileMenu.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    mobileMenuButton.innerHTML = "<div class='line'></div><br><div class='line'></div><br><div class='line'></div>";

  }


};

mobileMenuButton.addEventListener("click", mobileMenuButtonOnClick);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: large;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  z-index: 99;
}

.mr-0 {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.ml-auto {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}

.nav-bar {
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9);
  padding: 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 110px !important;
}

.nav-img {
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
}

.nav-options {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 3000ms ease-in-out;
}

.line {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 0.5px;
}

.moved-away {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  height: 0 !important;
  transition: all 2000ms ease-in-out;
}

.mobile-nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 10px;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-right: 40px !important;
  min-height: fit-content !important;
  line-height: 20vh;
  background-image: url("/resources/img_5.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 84vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  right: 0;
}

.mobile-menu li {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.mobile-options {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mobile-option {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat' sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.8);
  color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
}

.exit-btn {
  min-width: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  position: relative !important;
  bottom: 20px !important;
  z-index: 999999 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <nav class="mobile-nav">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="/resources/Copy of The Coders Club.png" class="nav-img"></a>
    <div class="nav-options">
      <button class="d-block mr-0 ml-auto hamburger-menu" id="mobile-menu-enter">
                  <div class="line"></div><br>
                   <div class="line"></div><br>
                  <div class="line"></div>
                </button>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="mobile-menu hidden" id="mobile-menu-id">
    <ul class="mobile-options">
      <a href="/about.html">
        <li><button class="mobile-option">About</button></li>
      </a>
      <a href="/classes.html">
        <li><button class="mobile-option" style="margin-top: 15%; margin-bottom: 15%;">Classes</button></li>
      </a>
      <a href="/contact.html">
        <li><button class="mobile-option">Contact</button></li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<main id="main-content">
  Some content. Lorem ipsum... Hello, World!

</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for including a runnable snippet. It might be helpful if you could describe what you see because it seems to me the action is consistent, not random. I can see the main content (not ‘the whole page’) rotating but I don’t see the X (close icon) appearing.

Comment: To animate the shrinking, you can also use `transform`, so the two transforms together shall be `transform: rotate(180deg) scaleY(0);`. To make the reverse animation, simply move the `transition` out from the `.moved-away` ruleset to `main`. You might also want to add `transform-origin`.

Comment: @A I added your recommended edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by random you mean that the exit click just restores the original state with no animation, that it because you have defined the `transition` property on `.move-away` class, and it is removed immediately on exit click.

You should move this `transition: all 2000ms ease-in-out;` into `main` styling (line 14 in the CSS file) to have the animation work both ways